# jQuery loop though elements to animate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a while loop appending spans into a div which is pagination for a slider. I have got as far as adding a class to the first child of the pagination container but I can't get my jQuery to animate the other numbers as the slider progresses. Apologies if I've described this issue awfully but I will include the code I have so far and a jsfiddle to show what's happening.

**jQuery:**

```
    // Change Orbit slide numbers so that they grow on active 
    var getSlides = $( '.orbit-slides-container' );
    var currentSlide = $('[data-orbit]').children('li');
    var currentSlideID = currentSlide.attr('id');
    var totalSlides = getSlides.children().length;
    var growingNumber = $( '.growing-slide-number' );
    var slideNumber = $( '.growing-slide-number' ).children('span').attr('id');
    var step = 0;

    // Function to add class os number grows.
    $.fn.grow = function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');             
    };

    // Function to shrink number to original size
    $.fn.growNext = function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().addClass('active');
    };

    $('.orbit-timer').after('<div class="growing-slide-number"></div>');

    // Loop through slides adding a number for each slide.
    while ( step < totalSlides ) {
        step++;
        $('.growing-slide-number').append('<span id="slide-' + step + '">' + step + '</span>');
    }
```

**SASS:**

```
.growing-slide-number { 
    @media #{$small-only} { display: none; }
    bottom: 45px;
    left: 25px;
    font-size: rem-calc(16); 
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.0);

    span {
        @include single-transition();
        margin-right: rem-calc(15);
        color: $white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;

    }
    span.active {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

If you need anymore info, please don't hesitate to ask.

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/h2q979v0/)

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work. 1st- No jQuery lib. 2nd- Extra end bracket.. I "fixed" it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/p7wbns46/)... But still, it doesn't work. You have to check for your images addresses since `.dev` leads to `ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION`. Read more about it [here](https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Sorry!! I've copy/pasted the generated html straight from my local dev environment... I'll update that right now as well as take a look at your "fixed" fiddle. I have jQuery loading in the header of my site and the app js (which I pasted into JSFiddle) loading after the footer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I've attempted to fix it, but stil not having the desired effect....  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7wbns46/8/)